# JavaScript "Undefined is not a function" when looping through an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, d3.js

I'm using d3 with Angular.  I have an array of objects initialized in my controller:

```
myApp.controller('LineChartCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.d3Data = [
    {date: "1-May-12", close: 98},
    {date: "30-Apr-12", close: 96},
    {date: '27-Apr-12', close: 75},
    {date: "22-Apr-12", close: 48}
  ];
}]);
```

In my d3 directive, which is receiving the data properly, I use the function:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.close = +d.close;
});
```

to parse the dates (not sure what the third line actually does... it converts something to a JavaScript `Number` object maybe...).  However, this second snippet returns the error: **"Undefined is not a function."**  Am I somehow accessing the properties of this object incorrectly?

Comment: It looks like `parseDate` should be defined using `d3.date.format(...).parse`. Can you show us that definition please?

Comment: It's in my comment to Vlad's answer... although his suggestion has been working just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing in JS as parseDate. You can try

```
d.date = new Date(d.date);
```

Comment: It's defined above:  `var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;`

It's a d3 thing.

Comment: Hoooo what.... it works though.  Wonder why it wasn't passing the `parseDate` function.  Thanks!